# Ubuntu desktop keeps "resetting" and putting my cursor in lower-right of the screen

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, window

Every now and then when I click or add a new window,

1. the entire screen freezes,
2. it turns purple, and
3. then the windows reappear again.

I recorded it [here](https://youtu.be/tnzlPOtvhSs)

Started when I was playing Minecraft and the pc froze, so I force-shutdown my computer.

note: Its not touchscreen.
note: I tried sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop and re-logged-in. Didn't work.

---

Apparently xcb crashes:

```
Apr 16 19:31:03 gnome-shell[14975]: [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
Apr 16 19:31:03 gnome-shell[14975]: [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
Apr 16 19:31:03 gnome-shell[14975]: [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Apr 16 19:31:03 gnome-shell[14975]: gnome-shell: ../../src/xcb_io.c:260: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Apr 16 19:31:03 gnome-shell[14975]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
```

[Full log](https://pastebin.com/rzCcp1A6)

It usually happens when I use applications that have custom GUIs (e.g. Gedit, Settings, Firefox, Emacs, System Monitor, Haguichi), and when I open/close windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Apparently I may have fixed it. What I did was uninstall gnome-shell-extensions, uninstall all extensions from /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions and rebooted, then removed from ~/.local/share/Trash/files and rebooted, then install gnome-shell-extensions. Then I uninstalled gnome-shell-extensions, and through chrome-gnome-extensions I installed dash-to-dock (since I needed to edit my dash because it wasn't rendering the right way and was acting if dash-to-dock was installed even if it wasn't at all) and kinda fiddled with it for a while.

*Maybe* was because in `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` there was dash-to-dock even if it wasn't installed, so whenever gnome would look for that, it would crash because it's not there. Type it in terminal and see if any extensions listed aren't actually installed. Then go ahead and install them, see if that works. If you don't need the extension, disable them first, then uninstall them.

Now obviously the desktop will be kinda flat--no desktop icons or app indicators. So you will have to install them again.

Links that worked for me:

- [GNOME desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301076/1141302)
- [App Indicators](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) ([StackOverflow Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030833/app-indicators-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04#1033801))

Links for hints:

- [Dock Settings](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_dock_settings/)
- [Launchpad Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1886059)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a touchscreen? My screen cracked and it caused some issues with the touchscreen. To fix it I opened up a terminal and typed the command 'xinput'. Under the pointer inputs I found the ID for my touchscreen then used the command

```
$ xinput disable your_id_here
```

Comment: its not a touchscreen :)