# Gnome desktop pixeled and no icons

Tags: gnome, icons, desktop-background, desktop-icons

I was playing with xfce and kde with ubuntu 20.04. When I came back to gnome (ubuntu-desktop, same if I use gnome classic), the actual desktop has no icons (I cannot click on it) and there are 'green pixels' randomly in the background (i.e. if I log in/out the green pixels change position in the screen.

I already tried:

-gnome-tweaks: enable icons in desktop (under 'extensions'). It does not work and after I exit gnome-tweaks the button is off again anyway (it does not stay 'on')

-reinstall: gnome, xorg

-reinstall desktop-icons [Repeating error: Can't install desktop-icons@csoriano](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280798/repeating-error-cant-install-desktop-iconscsoriano)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it
I first tried:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

which gave the error 'package not found'.
Then I simply navigated to the gnome interface on Chrome browser and searched for 'ding' extension. Installed it, the desktop is back now.